# Calculating ray-cylinder intersection points

Tags: 3d, computational-geometry

How is it done? I couldn't find a general formula/algorithm for this problem. I've read [this article](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/teaching/1999/AGraphHCI/SMAG/node2.html#SECTION00024000000000000000), I've managed to calculate the intersection points around the $z$-axis like they explained, but I didn't understand how to transform, rotate, and scale such that I can calculate the intersection points in an arbitrary location.

I'm trying to build a simple 3D engine, so detailed explanation/general formula would be great.

- My **ray** is defined with: origin point, normalized direction vector.
- My (infinite) **cylinder** is defined with: ray, radius.

If it's possible to extend the answers also for a finite cylinder-ray intersection, that would be more than great. Thanks in advance!

---

P.S. I've read many articles and comments (in Stack Overflow and elsewhere). Like I said, couldn't find a helpful solution for my problem.

P.P.S. I know how to calculate ray-triangle and ray-sphere intersections with arbitrary locations, if that helps.

Comment: Take the direction vector defining the cylinder, normalize it, and then use Gram-Schmidt to find an orthonormal basis. That would be one step towards rotation, and it's the hardest part.

Comment: I guess I can do it. but what's next after i've found an orthogonal basis? my linear algebra is rusty, but I can relearn how to do it.

Comment: Once you have the basis, you have the rotation matrix. It rotates the cylinder till its axis is aligned with one of the basis vectors. That means the cylinder can be given by a simple equation, e.g., $x^2 + y^2 = r^2$, without cross terms like $xy$ or $xz$. Then you apply the same rotation to the ray.

Answer (score 4):

The points at which the ray intersects the cylinder are the only ones on the line that are at a distance equal to the radius from the cylinder’s axis. Since you’re starting from a description of the cylinder as axis and radius, you can use a standard formula for the distance from a point to a line to find these points instead of trying to come up with an equation for the cylinder or trying to come up with a transformation into some standard configuration.

Let $\mathbf x(t) = \mathbf p_0+t \mathbf v$ be the parameterization of the ray with the given starting point and direction vector. Choose two points $\mathbf x_1$ and $\mathbf x_2$ on the cylinder’s axis: since that’s also defined by a ray (line?) you can choose the origin point of that line for $\mathbf x_1$ and add any convenient multiple of the axis direction vector to it for the other. Letting $r$ be the cylinder’s radius, the point-line distance formula gives following the quadratic equation in $t$: $${\lvert (\mathbf x(t)-\mathbf x_1)\times(\mathbf x(t)-\mathbf x_2)\rvert^2 \over \lvert \mathbf x_1-\mathbf x_2 \rvert^2}=r^2.$$ Expand and solve for $t$, rejecting any negative solutions, then compute $\mathbf x(t)$ for each resulting value of $t$. The one with the lesser $t$-value is the nearer to the origin of the ray.

For a finite cylinder, you can then project these points onto the cylinder’s axis and perform a range check. If you choose for $\mathbf x_1$ and $\mathbf x_2$ above the two points on the cylinder’s axis that bound the cylinder, then if $\mathbf p$ is a solution to the infinite intersection, it lies on the bounded cylinder iff $0\le(\mathbf p-\mathbf x_1)\cdot(\mathbf x_2-\mathbf x_1)\le(\mathbf x_2-\mathbf x_1)\cdot(\mathbf x_2-\mathbf x_1)$.

Comment: few questions:
a) the symbol "x" is the cross product?
b) the absolute value "| ... |" = length of the result vector of the cross-product?
c)solving for t, do i need to subtitute x(t)=P0+tv? so, for example, can I rewrite "X(t)-x1" as "(P0-x1)+tv"?

Comment: @Elyasaf755 Correct on all counts.

Answer (score 3):

Consider the shortest line segment between the cylinder axis and the ray and form a reference frame such that the cylindre axis is $z$ and the line segment is $x$. This frame is built by using the cross product of the two direction vectors (assumed to be unit), $\vec x=\vec c\times\vec r$, then $\vec z=\vec c,\vec y=\vec z\times\vec x$. Normalize these vectors. Then project the vector that joins a point of both lines onto $x$ to get the shortest segment. This projections is the vector $\vec d=(\vec{o_co_r}\cdot \vec x)\,\vec x$.

[image]

The origin point $\vec o=\vec o_c+s\,\vec c=\vec o_r+t\,\vec r-\vec d$ is found by solving

$$\begin{cases}
(\vec o_c+s\,\vec c)\cdot\vec y=(\vec o_r+t\,\vec r)\cdot\vec y,\\
(\vec o_c+s\,\vec c)\cdot\vec z=(\vec o_r+t\,\vec r)\cdot\vec z
\end{cases}$$ for $s$ or $t$.

In the new frame, the cylindre has the implicit equation

$$x^2+y^2=r^2$$

and the ray the parametric equations

$$\begin{cases}x=d,\\y=\beta t,\\z=\gamma t\end{cases}$$ where $d=\vec d\cdot\vec x,\beta=\vec r\cdot \vec y,\gamma=\vec r\cdot\vec z$.

Now

$$d^2+\beta^2t^2=r^2$$ gives the two intersections of the infinite cylindre with the infinite ray. You can restrict to $t\ge0$ for a half-ray.

If the cylindre has finite extent, the two basis will have the equations $z=z_{min}$ and $z=z_{max}$ (wrt to the origin $o$), giving the intersections by

$$z=\gamma t.$$

When you have the range of $t$ inside the infinite cylindre, and the range of $t$ between the two basis, it is an easy matter to find the common range. Then you can compute the two intersection points in the auxiliary frame and back-transform to the initial frame. Notice that the matrix of the back transform is the transpose of the direct transform, and that you invert

$$\vec q=R(\vec p-\vec o)$$ by

$$\vec p=R^{-1}\vec q+\vec o.$$

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, I have a problem though.
what should I do if the vector $\vec {o_co_r}$ (O_c-O_r) is orthogonal to vector $\vec x$? I ask this cause then vector $\vec d$ is vector 0 and I dont accept the 0 vector in my program.

Comment: @Elyasaf755: you are wrong to reject $\vec d=0$. This is not a problem and the above solution still works.

Comment: Ok, so for a Cylinder defined by: radius $r=4$ and a ray defined by origin point $o_c=(0,0,0)$ and direction vector $\vec c=(0,0,1)$, and a Ray defined by: origin point $o_r=(-5,0,0)$ and direction vector $\vec r=(1,0,0)$ , I solve for t and i get: $t1=4$, $t2=-4$. I didnt quiet understand what to do next. what $\vec q$ and $\vec p$ stands for? how $R$ and is defined? and how do I calculate $\vec q$ and $\vec p$?

Comment: @Elyasaf755: $\vec p,\vec q$ are dummy variables to explain how to invert the transformation. Review your theory of 3D rigid transforms/affine changes of variables.